# 'bun' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, tailwind-css, flowbite

i am integrating tailwind with flowbite react but this error occured

```
npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path C:\\Users\\ASUS\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Sankalp\\Frontend\\node_modules\\flowbite-react

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /d /s /c bun run build

npm ERR! 'bun' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\\_logs\\2024-03-31T07_04_56_478Z-debug-0.log

PS C:\\Users\\ASUS\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Sankalp\\Frontend\>
```

i am expecting tailwinnd and flowbite work properly but not working

Comment: The error suggests that you should install Bun. Have you?